# How to find moving average of a column with a variable interval(base on last n non-null values)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, moving-average

I have a data frame with the following format:

| Datetime | Value | MA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan | 1 | None |
| 2 Jan | 2 | None |
| 3 Jan | 1 | None |
| 4 Jan | N/A | None |
| 5 Jan | 2 | None |
| 6 Jan | N/A | None |
| 7 Jan | N/A | None |
| 8 Jan | 3 | None |

I wish to calculate the moving average of the "Value" column with the condition of the last 3 non-null values.

Desired output:

| Datetime | Value | MA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan | 1 | 1 |
| 2 Jan | 2 | 1.5 |
| 3 Jan | 1 | 1.33 |
| 4 Jan | None | 1.33 |
| 5 Jan | 2 | 1.67 |
| 6 Jan | None | 1.67 |
| 7 Jan | None | 1.67 |
| 8 Jan | 3 | 2 |

For example, in the 8 Jan row, the moving average takes the last 3 non-null value (3,2,1) to give a value of 2 while 3 Jan just take in (1,2,1) to calculate the moving average. Thus, I cannot use rolling.mean() method due to this scenario. I am also trying to avoid using a loop if possible as the dataframe is huge. What will be the best approach to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the NaNs with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), then compute the [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method=ffill` to fill in the missing values:

```
df['MA'] = (df.dropna(subset=['Value'])['Value']
              .rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
              .reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
           )
```

Output:

```
  Datetime  Value        MA
0    1 Jan    1.0  1.000000
1    2 Jan    2.0  1.500000
2    3 Jan    1.0  1.333333
3    4 Jan    NaN  1.333333
4    5 Jan    2.0  1.666667
5    6 Jan    NaN  1.666667
6    7 Jan    NaN  1.666667
7    8 Jan    3.0  2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I forgot that we can dropna prior to apply rolling.mean.

Comment: @Akav you're welcome, yes this makes things easy :)

Answer (score 3):

First remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), callculate rolling mean and then forward missing values:

```
df['MA'] = df['Value'].dropna().rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
df['MA'] = df['MA'].ffill()
```

Or add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with method `ffill`:

```
df['MA'] = (df['Value'].dropna().rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
                       .reindex(df.index, method='ffill'))
```

---

```
print (df)
  Datetime  Value        MA
0    1 Jan    1.0  1.000000
1    2 Jan    2.0  1.500000
2    3 Jan    1.0  1.333333
3    4 Jan    NaN  1.333333
4    5 Jan    2.0  1.666667
5    6 Jan    NaN  1.666667
6    7 Jan    NaN  1.666667
7    8 Jan    3.0  2.000000
```